# npm ERR! peer dep missing: - How to uninstall a globally installed npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I wanted to check all my globally installed packages and ran `npm list -g --depth 0`. I would like to uninstall some packages, for example prop-types and get rid of the error I get with 2 of them.

I want to uninstall prop-types. I did it with `npm uninstall -g prop-types` but it doesn't work. Also tried `npm uninstall -g prop-types --save`

```
~ npm list -g --depth 0             
/usr/local/lib
├── create-react-app@1.5.2
├── gatsby-cli@2.4.11
├── gitmoji-cli@1.9.2
├── json-server@0.14.2
├── mern-cli@2.5.0
├── nodemon@1.18.6
├── npm@6.9.2
└── strapi@3.0.0-alpha.24.1

npm ERR! peer dep missing: prop-types@^15.6.0, required by react-ga@2.5.7
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.6.2 || ^16.0, required by react-ga@2.5.7
```

And what about this `react-ga` ? It's not listed, but it looks like it needs some packages. How can I uninstall it if it's already installed? This is what I get when I try to uninstall it :

```
~ npm uninstall react-ga
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/philippe/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/philippe/package.json'
npm WARN philippe No description
npm WARN philippe No repository field.
npm WARN philippe No README data
npm WARN philippe No license field.

audited 1 package in 0.62s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: I would say `react-ga` is a dependency of `create-react-app`. Try increasing the depth to see if you can see it listed.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the peer dep missing error, you must remove the `@gatsby-cli` package

```
npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli
```

Comment: Why specifically this package? How did you come to this conslusion?